# One liner add flag if variable exist

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to improve my bash knowledge as well as make my code more organized

What I am trying to do here is add the flag -u with the variable $user only if the variable exist otherwise don't mention the -u flag.

Here is what I tried to do

```
echo "Running: ps if [[ -n "$user"]]; then -u $user fi | wc -l"
```

If $user exist is it will print the amount of proccesses $user has

however if $user does not exist just show the amount of proccesses of all users

Important to note that I need it to be this way (inside the echo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not going to use `echo` to output variable data because it's unnecessary in this case and `echo` may also modify the data under some circumstances (see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)). It's also inelegant as you'd need a command substitution, and therefore it would require the shell to temporarily hold the output from `ps` in memory.

Instead, I would probably write the code like this to make it readable:

```bsh
echo Running:
if [ -n "$user" ]; do
    ps -u "$user"
else
    ps
fi
```

or, if you want to start compacting it down into more unreadable chunks,

```bsh
echo Running:
ps ${user:+-u "$user"}
```

The expansion `${variable:+word}` would expand to `word` if the variable `variable` was set and not empty.  Remove the `:` to only expand to `word` if the variable is set (but possibly empty).  This expansion is standard, so any POSIX-like shell would support it.

If you, for whatever reason, want this on one line, then write it on one line:

```bsh
echo Running:;ps ${user:+-u "$user"}
```

or, using the if-then-else variation,

```bsh
echo Running:;if [ -n "$user" ]; do ps -u "$user"; else ps; fi
```